# o3d javascript uncaught reference error

Tags: javascript, o3d, referenceerror

im new to javascript and am intersted in creating a small o3d script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test Game Website</title>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="o3djs/base.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" id="myscript">

o3djs.require('o3djs.camera');

window.onload = init;

function init(){
 document.write("jkjewfjnwle");
}

</script>

<div align="background">
 <div id="game_container" style="margin: 0px auto; clear: both; background-image: url('./tmp.png'); width: 800px; height:600px; padding: 0px; background-repeat: no-repeat; padding-top: 1px;"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

the browser cant seem to find o3djs/base.js in this line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="o3djs/base.js"></script>
```

and gives me an uncaught referenceerror at this line

```
 o3djs.require('o3djs.camera');
```

Obviously, because it can't find the o3djs/base.js...

I have installed the o3d pluggin from google and they say that should be IT 
ive tried on firefox, ie and chrome

thanks

Comment: Where did you put that javascript source ("base.js")?  Where is your page being served from?

Comment: im just trying to run the page locally for now. Thats the thing, all o3d's site tells me to do is install the plugin and i'm good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files that your HTML point to (CSS, JS, links) are searched relative to the document's path.

E.g. if your document's URL is `http://localhost/foo/testpage.html`, in this case you must put mentioned `base.js` in `http://localhost/foo/o3djs/`, etc. So, if your localhost is at C:\Server (assuming you use some Windows-like environment), the file must be called C:\Server\foo\o3djs\base.js.

Comment: it's too bad google didn't mention that I had to download a zip, or even mentionned where to download it. I had to get it from a sample.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you include all the other files needed by the API, most of them can be found here: http://o3d.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples_webgl/o3djs/